# Problem with JS add and remove class for elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code that adds or removes a class from elements. But it does this only for the menu, but not for the content (a huge white square in the middle), although it should for both at the same time. I need that when clicking on any button in the menu, the 'is-active' class changes both in the menu and in the content.

[without clicking on the menu.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM2pl.png)

[with a click on the menu.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ammqw.png)

```
  const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.list'))
  const play = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.play'))

  const clearActiveClass = (element, className = 'is-active') => {
    element.find(item => item.classList.remove(`${ className }`))
  }

  const setActiveClass = (element, index, className = 'is-active') => {
    element[index].classList.add(`${ className }`)
  }

  const checkoutTabs = (item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {

      if (item.classList.contains('is-active')) return
      console.log(item)

      clearActiveClass(list)
      clearActiveClass(play)

      setActiveClass(list, index)
      setActiveClass(play, index)
    })
  }

  list.forEach(checkoutTabs)
```

Comment: `.find()`: this will stop running as soon as it finds one element that matches your condition (it found it, no need to go further). Maybe you meant to use `.forEach()` instead

Comment: Your `find` inner function is not appropriate for `find` functionality.

Comment: well, if you replace find with forEach, then the buttons stopped working. Can you tell me what needs to be done to make it work? @blex

Comment: not related to your question, but since `className` is always a string there's no difference between ``${ className }`` and simply `className`, so you can make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner function to `find` needs to be something that finds an element containing className.  Once you have found the element, you can remove the className class.

```
  const clearActiveClass = (element, className = 'is-active') => {
    element.find(item => item.classList.contains(className)).classList.remove(className);
  }
```